# Finding and deleting DIVs, page written in php

Tags: php, html

I'm struggling to find where I go to delete a div that is on a web page.
The page is written in php so when I go to the element inspector I can find the div and delete it but obviously that doesn't save and I need to edit it in the back end. This is where I'm stuck because I don't know where to find the bit of code I need to delete.

I'm new to php so is it a bit of code in there.
I'm trying to delete the £2.40 on this page as it displays twice. 
http://chumpspotter.com/chinapalace/?page_id=5
Also im trying to delete the <.br> in the form but I don't know where its stored.
Any help would be much appreciated!

This is the code:

```
>  </td>
>  <td><span class='pricedisplay'>&#163;2.60</span></td>
>  <td class="wpsc_product_price wpsc_product_price_0"><span class="pricedisplay"><span
> class='pricedisplay'>&#163;2.60</span></span></td>
>  <td class="wpsc_product_remove wpsc_product_remove_0">
>  <form action="http://chumpspotter.com/chinapalace/?page_id=5" method="post" class="adjustform remove">
>  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="0" /><br />
>  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="0" /><br />
>  <input type="hidden" name="wpsc_update_quantity" value="true" /><br />
>  <input type="submit" value="Remove" name="submit" /><br />
>  </form>
```

I want to delete one of the "span class=pricedisplay" but dont know where I would look in the .php for this?

Comment: hi chris, welcome to SO :) read http://stackoverflow.com/faq and then provide some code, so we may give you any help :)

Comment: You're linking to a page that needs a context. To us it only shows that the cart is empty. Even tough you don't know exactly where the duplicate code is you should know the area where it is and you can paste it here otherwise we can't help you. Your issue can also be from javascript

Comment: Take a look at your templates for the WP-ECommerce plugin on the backend. -1 because your link goes to a shopping cart page.

Comment: It looks like you're using a CMS for the site, without knowing what it is, it's hard to help.  Most likely, there's a template for the checkout page that you need to find and modify - it could be an actual  .php file or it could be saved in the DB.  Again, knowing what type of CMS is pretty important.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest these solutions:

1. If the website is yours, or anyway if you're able to work on the page, just don't `echo` the span.
2. If you have no control over the page, you may want to use regexes, which are anyway too complex.
3. If you don't want to use regexes, just replace the `<span class="pricedisplay">` with a span that doesn't display the input: `<span style="display:none;">`. This is a simple, yet powerful solution if you can't modify the page.

To delete the `<.br>` just open the PHP code in a common text editor and use the `Find and Replace` function, that's easy.